# Read file, create new file with only the blocks of snippets in it

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like:

```
text texttext texttext texttext texttext text
text texttext texttext texttext text
==========[start log]====
..
..
..
==============


testtextexttexttesttextexttext
testtextexttexttesttextexttext

==========[start log]====
..
..
..
==============
```

So I want to create a new file that just has the blocks of:

```
==========[start log]=== 
..
..
..
=============
```

All `===` blocks have 2 blank lines below them.

The `...` inside the blocks is actually text.

Comment: looks like homework :) please tag appropriately if so.

Comment: no its actually work, log file parsing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you even tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: i got to reading the file in a .py file thus far.

Comment: `print "test"` isn't working in my .py files, how do I output to console for simple logging?

Comment: "print "test" isn't working in my .py files".  That's more-or-less impossible.  Are you using Python 3.  If so, that's bad syntax?  If not, you're not telling us everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

regex = re.compile('==============.+?==============', re.DOTALL)

with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
matches = regex.findall(content)
```

Comment: do I write matches to a file then? do I have to loop it?

Comment: @codecompleting, yes. You can just do `for match in matches: out_file.write(match)`.

Comment: actually the first delimiter looks like `======[start log]======`  do I have to escape the brackets?

Comment: "do I have to escape the brackets?"  Of course.  When in doubt, please read the information on the `re` module.  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html.  This module is essential.

Answer (score 3):

You can go line by line, and only copy what you want.

```
old = open('old.txt', 'r')
new = open('new.txt', 'w')

in_block = False

for line in old:
    if line.startswith('===='):
        in_block = not in_block # Oposite
        new.write(line)
    elif in_block:
        new.write(line)

old.close()
new.close()
```

It puts this in 'new.txt'.

```
==============
..
..
..
==============
==============
..
..
..
==============
```

Comment: You should probably use `with open('old.txt','r') as old:` and `with open('new.txt','w') as new:` to guarantee that the files are properly closed.

Comment: From a technical stand point, yeah, I should.  From a person who's trying to read the code; the indentation isn't really justified.  I added the `.close()` code at the bottom.

Comment: "the indentation isn't really justified".  Actually, I find that the clarity and unambiguous correctness more than offset the indentation.  Also, there are some workarounds: http://copypasteprogrammer.blogspot.com/2010/03/nested-with-statements-are-nice.html.

Answer (score 0):

Really easy with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/==============/,/==============/p' example.txt
```

Yields:

```
==============
..
..
..
==============
==============
..
..
..
==============
```

Answer (score 0):

From my reading, I think you're trying not to include the text outside the '===='.

```
raw = open(the_file).read()
parts = raw.split("=============")
new_parts = []
for ii, part in enumerate(parts):
    if not (ii % 2): continue
    new_parts.append(part)
new_raw = "=============".join(new_parts)
open(new_file, 'w').write(new_raw)
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use a generator to handle the "state change" between the material prior to a block and the material within a block.

You're really reading a head-tail sequence.  The head is (text, '===...', more text, '===...').  The tail is a head-tail sequence.  The definition is tail-recursive which allows us to flatten it into a loop

```
def gen_block_sequence( some_source ):
    block_iter= tier(some_source):
    for line in block_iter:
        if line == '==============':
            block= list( gen_head(block_iter)
            yield block

def gen_head( block_iter ):
    for line in block_iter:
        if line == '==============':
            break
        yield line
```

While this is long, I find that it generalizes well to accommodate lots of additional processing and decision-making.